# Why doesn't Vista create shortcuts in Start menu?

Tags: windows-vista, shortcuts, start-menu

I am using Windows Vista Home Premium (64-bit) on a system with 64-bit processor. Whenever I install a PC game, Vista does not create any shortcuts or program folders in "Start Menu -> All Programs". I have to open the `C:\Program Files (x86)` and find the game folder, and create the shortcut manually. Any comments on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Games in Vista usually does not create game shortcuts on the start menu. The new thing is that they register themselves in the Games menu. You can find this by going to Start->Games and all your games should be listed there.

Comment: I've found the shortcuts in Game Explorer under Start -> Games. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not true : most games just add a shortcut on the start menu. The only games that I have installed and that add an icon in the Game menu was Microsoft Games (eg Flight Simulator 10 and Gear of War).

Comment: I'm telling the truth, dude. Now I upgraded to Win7 and all game shortcuts are always automatically added to Start -> All Programs -> Games. Some of the games: PES 2009, Dead Space, Call of Duty - World at War etc. My Windows is genuine and Home Premium.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts and menu options are created by the application installer.  Sounds like the installers of whatever games you are installing do not add shortcuts or menu options.

Comment: I installed those games on Windows XP several times, and shortcuts were created. I install them exactly with the same way as XP in Vista, and I don't understand why there are no shortcuts in Start Menu and desktop. It must be something related to Vista.

Comment: Some of the games: PES 2009, Dead Space, Call of Duty - World at War, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The game installer is probably looking for the wrong shortcuts directory.

In XP this was: `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Start Menu`
In Vista this is: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

The directory is probably wrongly hard-coded in the installer. It should rather have retrieved it using the Windows API.

However, the shortcuts can probably still be found in the old XP directory. Just move them to the right Vista directory.